# What JavaScript regular expression would I use to find out that a string contains an open HTML tag but not a close HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, regex

What JavaScript regular expression would I use to find out that a string contains an open HTML tag but not a close HTML tag. For example as follows:

```
var tags = ['h1', 'div', 'span']; // tag to look for

var str1 = 'lorem ipsum <h1>hello world'; // here it is!

var str2 = 'boo foo 123 test'; // this one doesn't have any

var str3 = '<span>boo-boo</span>'; // this has the tags but it is not the case as we only need the ones that have open tags and not close tags.
```

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex is likely to yield problematic results; regular expressions can't match balanced pairs recursively (though some versions, but not JavaScript, have extensions that make this possible). To do this properly, you'd need a proper parser... and assuming you're talking about client-side JS, you'll probably want to do the parsing on the server (for performance and page weight reasons).

Comment: Is this a simplified example? Will you need to check for nested tags, or flat tags? Can they have attributes?

Answer (score 6):

You [can't parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).  Keeping track of open/close tag pairs requires a [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28data_structure%29), and a regular expression is a [finite-state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine), which has no stack.

Answer (score -1):

```
'(\<(/?[^\>]+\>)'
```

This expression is for HTML tags.